# Use custom script in Intelij IDEA to run sbt shell

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Is it possible to run sbt shell in Intelij IDEA using custom script instead of built in sbt or sbt from sbt-launch.jar? Why I need this, for example there is some project which uses custom script to set config file location, VM parameters, and other options for sbt and this script is shared in version control system. And it would be very convenient to just specify for IntelliJ IDEA location of such script.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. However, to pass project-specific sbt command line parameters to sbt you may place a `.sbtopts` in your project directory, and likewise a `.jvmopts` for VM parameters.